# Determining when all bindings for a BindingSource are complete

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am working with a Windows Forms application. I have a number of things that I need to do in the UI when the user navigates from one row to the next in a form. I would like to do these things once all of the data bindings for the controls have been completed because the order in which they are done is important. Is there a good way to determine when all of the bindings are complete? I could use the BindingSource.BindingComplete event, but many of the the things that need to be done require that the binding for multiple controls be complete. I could find a way to keep track of this, but I thought that I'd ask to see if anybody had a simple way of telling when all of the bindings for a BindingSource have been completed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code to show us when and how you are setting up your bindings?

Comment: Is everything happening on the UI thread?  Is the databinding all happening in response to the change in row (ie, in an event handler for the row selection changed)?

Comment: yes all are happening on the UI. Also I have bind it to the datagridview

Comment: Have you ever found a working solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can find what is the last control that is binded by tracing control name at each BindingControl execution.

```
Private Sub BindingSource_BindingComplete(sender As Object, e As BindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles BindingSource.BindingComplete

    Debug.Print(e.Binding.Control.Name.ToString)

End Sub
```

Since you know it, you can check this event arg to know when the last control has been binded.

```
Private Sub BindingSource_BindingComplete(sender As Object, e As BindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles BindingSource.BindingComplete
    If e.Binding.Control.Name = "controlName" Then
        'Do things...
    End If
End Sub
```

FabiD

Comment: The original author mentioned you solution, but pointed out that it was problematic because he needs to know when multiple controls have been bound.